# What filter was used?

Tags: effect

This accounts filter always moves when you scroll through the photos. Does anyone know how to get this or what it's called?https://instagram.com/p/BCROputkCX3/

Comment: Without describing the effect you desire to emulate this question is useless because 1) It will get lost in all of the other "How do I get this effect?/WHat filter was used?" questions 2) We have no way of knowing what in particular, about the linked example (that may later be a dead link), you are trying to emulate.

http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions

Answer (score 2):

The filter is simply either lightening every other line or darkening it. The "movement" you see when scrolling is an optical illusion. I'm not sure of which photo filters create this effect, but if you use the "Bad TV" filter in Apple's Final Cut Pro X or Motion you can get the same effect. I imagine there's probably a similar filter for Photoshop and other photo editing apps.